# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcaffe

Tags: linux, ubuntu, c++, make, caffe

I installed Caffe-cpu on my Ubuntu 18.04 via the apt-get command, as it instructs on their [official website](https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html):

```
sudo apt install caffe-cpu
```

But when trying to run a sample from a [git repo](https://github.com/Pratik08/Vis-DSS), it needs the header files (`caffe.hpp`). For that, I downloaded the latest Caffe Git repo with the sources. But it also complains at the make time:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcaffe
```

My understanding of similar problmes is that apparently it needs to link to `caffe.so`, but I can't find it anywhere on my machine. What's the problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not mentioned on Caffe's official website. But I have to use

```
sudo apt install caffe-cpu-dev
```

to produce those missing header files and `.so` files.